# echo a message if the page doesn't have the required ID?

Tags: php

I am trying to echo a message on my php page if the page doesn't have the required ID.

this is part of a facebook iframe page app. so I am using the following code to get the facebook page id that displays my php page.

getting the page id works fine and i can simply echo the page ID on my page and it will display the page as it should.

But for some reason I cannot echo the message "Not Allowed" if the page doesn't contain the page ID!

this is my current code:

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
if( $page = $signed_request['page'] ) {
   // echo $page['id'];
    $pageid = $page['id'];
}elseif( $signed_request['page'] = "" ) {
   // echo $page['id'];
    echo "Not Allowed";
}
```

could someone please advise on this?

Thanks

Comment: You're assigning `=` instead of comparing `==` with your conditional statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use double `==` in condition:

```
$signed_request['page'] = ""
```

so it should be:

```
$signed_request['page'] == ""
```

It's also possible that the same is with line:

`if( $page = $signed_request['page'] ) {`

but it's hard to say if we have only this code.

Comment: oh my god. I feel so stupid now. this worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
if( $page == $signed_request['page'] ) {
   // echo $page['id'];
    $pageid = $page['id'];
}else{
   // echo $page['id'];
    echo "Not Allowed";
}
```

Try something like this.